# Dynamic SQL Create User Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to create a user script that will pull usernames from a table and put it into a variable, but I am running into a bunch of errors. Here's what Ive got.

```
USE AP
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT DB_ID('AP'))
        DROP TABLE NewLogins

CREATE TABLE NewLogins
    (LoginName VARCHAR(128))

INSERT INTO NewLogins
VALUES ('BBrown'), ('CChaplin'), ('DDyer'), ('EEbbers')

DECLARE NewLogins CURSOR
STATIC
FOR (SELECT LoginName, SUBSTRING(LoginName, 1, 4) FROM NewLogins)

DECLARE @LoginName VARCHAR(128), @Password VARCHAR(128)

OPEN NewLogins
FETCH NEXT FROM NewLogins
INTO @LoginName, @Password
DECLARE @DropLogin VARCHAR(200)
SET @DropLogin ='DROP LOGIN ' + @LoginName + ''
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN

        IF EXISTS (SELECT DB_ID('AP'))
            EXEC @DropLogin

        FETCH NEXT FROM NewLogins

        Declare @sqlstmt VARCHAR(200)
        SET @sqlstmt='CREATE LOGIN '+@LoginName +' WITH PASSWORD ='''+ LOWER(@Password) +'9999'''
        PRINT @sqlstmt
        EXEC (@sqlstmt)

        DECLARE @CreateUser VARCHAR(200)
        SET @CreateUser ='CREATE USER '+@LoginName +'FOR LOGIN ' + @LoginName

        DECLARE @AddMemberToGroup VARCHAR(200)
        SET @AddMemberToGroup ='EXEC sp_addrolemember ' + @LoginName +', ' + 'PaymentEntry'

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = @LoginName)
            BEGIN
            EXEC @CreateUser
            EXEC @AddMemberToGroup
        END
    END
CLOSE NewLogins
DEALLOCATE NewLogins
```

For some reason I keep getting errors where it says:

```
CREATE LOGIN BBrown WITH PASSWORD ='bbro9999'
Msg 15025, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The server principal 'BBrown' already exists.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 45
Could not find stored procedure 'CREATE USER BBrownFOR LOGIN BBrown'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 46
Could not find stored procedure 'EXEC sp_addrolemember BBrown, PaymentEntry'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 28
Could not find stored procedure 'DROP LOGIN BBrown'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start off, you will always get a resultset from `SELECT DB_ID('AP')`. That resultset might have a `NULL` value in the one row/column that it returns, but it still exists, so using `IF EXISTS` there is a mistake. You need to check, `IF DB_ID('AP') IS NOT NULL`.

Next, you're opening yourself up to SQL Injection. You should research it very carefully and understand why the dynamic SQL that you're using is dangerous.

Finally, when using `EXEC` with a string of dynamic SQL, you need to put it in braces, otherwise SQL thinks that you're trying to call a stored procedure. The syntax for the `EXEC` function and the `EXEC` command are slightly different. So, you would need `EXEC(@CreateUser)`